# How can I embed React Apps in WordPress blocks for rendering for end users?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, block

I want to embed my React app in a WordPress Block and provide this app for end users.  My expectation is that I can put my app in view.js, but I cannot get view.js content to render.  I can run React fine in the Block editor through Edit() in edit.js, but this is because registerBlockType uses {edit: Edit} in the block configuration object.  But there is no equivalent {render: Render} provision.  The closest I can get to embedding my app is to output it as HTML in render.php.  File render.php renders fine (as expected for a dynamic app where the save callback is null), but this is not sufficient; I need to use React.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/create-block/block-anatomy/

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to use createRoot from wordpress element functions, https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-element/.  This lets us display React components inside a DOM node.  Steps:

1. Define the DOM node in render.php:

   ```
    <div id="replacement_id">content to be replaced</div>
   ```
2. Render the app at this node by adding this to view.js:

   ```
    window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
        const domElement = document.getElementById("replacement_id");
        const root = createRoot(domElement);
        root.render(<App />);
    });
   ```